# Docker cannot clone from host's repo

Tags: docker

I have a CI server that runs Atlassian Stash(Git repo), Bamboo(CI) server within the same host with local ip address of 10.1.10.141. One of the build task requires docker to run couple processes within its dedicated folder and generate some files based on this build process.
Below is the command that initiates docker.

```
docker run -v ~bamboo/.ssh:/.ssh -v ~urban/bin:/urban/bin -v ${HOME}/build/search:/search -v ${PWD}:/bamboo  -w /bamboo urban /bin/bash -c '/urban/bin/bamboo.search-deploy.sh ${bamboo.staging_deploy_server_ip} staging'
```

Basically within and empty dir docker initiated and several necessary dirs located in the host are mounted to the container and bamboo.search-deploy.sh is initiated.

bamboo.search-deploy calls another file in the same host  and executes it within docker container.

```
curl -sL 'http://git.myhost.com/urbansea' | bash
```

Which contains various scripts that runs such as "git clone" `ssh://git@git.myhost.com:7999/sea/load.git ${BUILD_LOAD}"`

Now this is where everything fails.Outside of docker; meaning in the host, i can git clone from the stash (in the same host), but if i try to clone within docker it times out.

Host and docker container runs on 2 separate interfaces with the following ip address.
Docker container can curl, ping, git clone any outside repo with no problem. ssh keys are also present and they do work with the stash.

```
Host: eth0: 10.1.10.141
Docker: docker0: 172.17.42.1
```

I created an entire clone of the same set up in a virtual host with seperate ip and executed the git clone and it worked.

I suspect this may be an issue related to how docker bridges to host network card but i dont have a solid understanding of how to solve the issue.

Host runs on ubuntu 12.10 kernel 3.5

```
Linux dev 3.5.0-51-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 21:19:10 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I know docker docs states to run it on 3.8 but i have some other issues related to 12.10 being end of life.

I also tried to run docker on an interface with an ip address that is within the same subnet of the host ip but same problem persisted. Here is the link to [blog post](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/) that i followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out problem was related to ip tables blocking the ip address of docker container. Upon checking out the logs, i saw ufw blocking various ip addresses in the same subnet (172.17.0.0/24) which happens to be docker's ip. It was resolved by issuing:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.17.0.9/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Docker renews the ip address every time it is launched so it is better to ip range than static ip.